# How to define custom slug for child category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

In my wordpress website I have a custom post dancer and dancer category is location which has sub location
hierarchy is as follow

Example Main Location  US
then child location is Newyork
so url is [www.example.com/us/newyork](http://www.example.com/us/newyork)
but my required url should be ([www.example.com/us/find-newyork](http://www.example.com/us/find-newyork)), want to update all child locations with find word in url

I want to add find- in all sub location , i have around 5000 sub location

```
function dancer_post_type() {

 // Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Hostesss', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentytwentyone' 
   ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Hostess', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentytwentyone' 
     ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Hostesss', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Hostesss', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Hostesss', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Hostesss', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Hostesss', 
'twentytwentyone' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Hostesss', 
 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Hostesss', 
  'twentytwentyone' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Hostesss', 
  'twentytwentyone' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentytwentyone' 
   ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 
  'twentytwentyone' ),
);
  
 // Set other options for Custom Post Type
  
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'dancers', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'description'         => __( 'dancers news and reviews', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt',  'thumbnail',  'custom-fields', ),
    // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'type' ),
    /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
    * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
    * is like Posts.
    */
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-universal-access-alt',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest' => true,

);
  
// Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'dancers', $args );
$cat_labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Hostess Location', 'taxonomy general name', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Hostess Location', 'taxonomy singular name', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'Locations', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Hostess Location:', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Hostess Location Name', 'twentytwentyone' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Hostess Location', 'twentytwentyone' ),
);

  $cat_args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $cat_labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'hierarchical' => true ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'dancer_category', array( 'dancers' ), $cat_args );

}  
add_action( 'init', 'dancer_post_type', 0 );
```

I want to update find in all child location slug
[image]